# Script not working when I place jquery.js on footer

Tags: jquery

I place `jquery.js` on my footer before `</body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

And why this code is not firing? But when I move jquery.js on header before `</head>` it working fine..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub-category").hide();
    $("#main-category").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'id=' + id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/select-category/",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#sub-category").show();
                $("#sub-category").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know why code above is not firing when I include `jquery.js` on my footer.

Comment: Where in your page is the ready() call? If it's before the include then the function wont have been defined by the time you call it.

Comment: Solution: Keep it in `<head>`, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you actually put the `$(document).ready(function () { });` block before jQuery library. jQuery has to be loaded even before `$(document).ready(function () { });` block in order to make it work. However, in all cases, keep jQuery in `<head>`, that's the right place for it

Comment: Keep jQuery in `<head>` a best temporary solution. I just wonder when I put `alert('fired')` around the code it working, but the rest is not firing.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple shim for this reason precisely. It creates a global jQuery (and $) object that are only capable of queuing functions for domReady. It is very tiny so you can inline it in the HEAD tag (inline to avoid the whole issue of a dns lookup, latency, etc) and then any code in the body written as you describe will still function properly.

https://github.com/withjam/jqshim-head

The shim essentially stores all of the functions passed to jQuery() or jQuery().ready(), waits for the real jQuery to be available, then passes them into the real jQuery() call to proceed with the isDomReady cycle.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Place the following in your page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      // Place-holder function to handle jquery, before jquery is loaded  (as jquery is loaded in the footer)
      (function(w,d,u){w.readyQ=[];w.bindReadyQ=[];function p(x,y){if(x=="ready"){w.bindReadyQ.push(y);}else{w.readyQ.push(x);}};var a={ready:p,bind:p};w.$=w.jQuery=function(f){if(f===d||f===u){return a}else{p(f)}}})(window,document)
</script>
```

Place this in the footer after you load the jquery script:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       // This will make it possible to declare jquery inline
       (function($,d){$.each(readyQ,function(i,f){$(f)});$.each(bindReadyQ,function(i,f){$(d).bind("ready",f)})})(jQuery,document)
</script>
```

Then declare all of your jquery inline in a $(document).ready(function(){}); call and it works.

I can't remember where I found this code, but it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script included before 'jquery.js'? Then it won't work because of not being able to access the jQuery functions.

For helping to debug consider using the add-on 'Firebug' in Firefox or the integrated Developer Tools in Chrome/Chromium. Both open by pressing F12.